# How do you run unit tests in Netbeans 8.0 without downloading Maven dependencies?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, netbeans, junit

I am using Netbeans 8.0 and running unit tests in Java.  When I run the tests, it downloads all the dependencies.  I want it to not download the dependencies and just assume everything is up to date.

I tried adding offline under Actions, but it doesn't work.

Also, I would like to re-compile my project, which it does not do automatically when I test.

Answer (score 1):

you don't mention the netbeans version, but by default 8.0 will do compile on saving. So you have to turn it off to get the sources compiled on test execution.

dependencies should be downloaded in your local repository once and cached, unless you have some maven settings turned on to keep on retrying (eg. for snapshots).

AFAIK you cannot turn --offline per action mapping, just globally in Tools/Options.

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.0.  If I changed a setting to have it always download, I don't know what setting I changed.  It would seem my code does not compile when it saves as the tests don't run off the current version unless I do a build.

I'm afraid I don't see an Options menu under tools, so if you have more advice about how to get to offline mode, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you are on MacOSX, it's Netbeans/Preferences.

Comment: once within the options dialog, it's Java/Maven